# why is $_REQUEST empty

Tags: php, arrays, request

I have Ubuntu 10.10 with apache2, php 5.3.3-1 and mysql 5.1.

I am passing some values to a page via URL. On that page, if I do `print_r($_GET)`, then I see the array contents. But if I do `print_r($_REQUEST)` the array is empty. Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: This is an old problem... Have you tried `var_dump($GLOBALS['_REQUEST']);`?

Comment: yes $GLOBALS['_REQUEST'] is empty too

Comment: Check out `register_long_arrays` and `auto_globals_jit` in **php.ini**. Sometimes it works, when you turn off both of them (restart server after changing php.ini). What values you have there? Also take a look of the @PaulP's answer bellow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Also try check ["request_order"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order) option in php.ini:

> This directive determines which super global data (G,P,C,E & S) should
> be registered into the super global array REQUEST. If so, it also
> determines the order in which that data is registered. The values for
> this directive are specified in the same manner as the variables_order
> directive, EXCEPT one. Leaving this value empty will cause PHP to use
> the value set in the variables_order directive. It does not mean it
> will leave the super globals array REQUEST empty.

```
Default Value: None

Development Value: "GP"

Production Value: "GP"

http://php.net/request-order

request_order = "GP"
```

Comment: Added link to the PHP man page. You beat me to it so I removed my answer! :)

Comment: thanks the issue is resolved. the value was empty in php.ini but the funny thing is that i have the same settings on my server but over there it works. request_order no value and variables_order EGPCS. Thanks again tough.

Comment: Hi PaulP, I have the same problem with Hawkseye, but i found in my php.ini file the request_order is already set to "GP" and also the variables_order is set to "GPCS". I didn't do any changes. I restarted the PHP server but still doesn't work. I'm using nginx 1.4.4 with PHP 5.5.8 for windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if your post body larger than post_max_size or upload_max_filesize  which in the php.ini may be cause $_POST and $_REQUEST empty too.