# 5.3.3 update issue

Tags: php, facebook

Since i recently had my servers upgraded to PHP 5.3.3 stuff have been going wrong. Everything was working last week and now all this.. Here is the issue.

I am setting up my Facebook application but it will not recognise **$_REQUEST["CODE"]** even if it does appear in my address bar it comes through as blank... and then my token request URL comes through with an error here is my code...

```
// INCLUDE FB CONFIG
include('admin/includes/config.inc.php');
include('admin/classes/dbconnect.class.php');

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
$dialog_url = "";
$token_url = "";
$access_token = "";

// CHECK FOR THE REQUEST CODE - IF EMPTY REDIRECT TO THE oAUTH URL. 
if(empty($code)) {

    // SETUP PERMISSIONS - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=". APP_ID ."&redirect_uri=". urlencode(APP_POST_URL)."&scope=email";
    echo('<script>top.location.href="' . $dialog_url . '"</script>');
}

// SETUP ACCESS TOKEN URL
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
. APP_ID . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode(APP_POST_URL) 
. "&client_secret=" . APP_SECRET 
. "&code=" . $code;
```

Here is the error that I keep getting!!!

> Notice: Undefined index: code in /usr/wwws/users/heroadfgsm/votepoll/index.php on line 10 Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=##############&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Ftestapplication%2F&client_secret=###################&code=): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /usr/wwws/users/heroadfgsm/votepoll/index.php on line 35 Notice: Undefined index: access_token in /usr/wwws/users/heroadfgsm/votepoll/index.php on line 39 Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /usr/wwws/users/heroadfgsm/testfolder/index.php:10) in /usr/wwws/users/heroadfgsm/testfolder/facebook_api/facebook.php on line 37 Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /usr/wwws/users/heroadfgsm/testfolder/facebook_api/base_facebook.php on line 988

Comment: but $code is not empty, because it loads the "access_token" URL, right?

Comment: Try looking at the answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701588/why-is-request-empty

Answer (score 0):

to solve your Notice: Undefined index: error problem  `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`

and check if openssl is  ON in php.ini file