# what in PHP server setup would cause $_REQUEST to be empty?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, request

I've been developing a WordPress site on my local machine and hosting on my own server. Everything runs perfectly.

Since moving to the client server, certain functions in the editor have stopped working. Specifically, those involving ajax requests. I have looked into things and it's exiting with `die(0)` in `admin-ajax.php` at the following code:

```
// Require an action parameter
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) )
    die( '0' );
```

further reading sees `$_REQUEST` being reset during `wp_magic_quotes()` in `wp-includes/load.php` as follows:

```
$_REQUEST = array_merge( $_GET, $_POST );
```

What might be the issue with the PHP setup on the server that might make `$_REQUEST` remain blank after `wp_magic_quotes()` during `ajax-admin.php`?

If I edit `ajax-admin.php` to add the `$_REQUEST` reset:

```
$_REQUEST = array_merge( $_GET, $_POST );

// Require an action parameter
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) )
    die( '0' );
```

...then everything ajax in the editor works as it should.

But I would rather not edit core files, so would like to know how I can change the server setup to get things working with the standard files?

**Setup Details:**
Wordpress 3.4.2
PHP 5.4.5 using Apache 2.0 Handler
Unix server

**PHP settings:**
request_order: no value
variables_order: GPCS

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's a good idea to [check the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order)

Comment: Temporarily disable all plugins and any non-default theme. Do you still have the problem? Which Wordpress and which PHP version are you using?

Comment: Also put a `var_dump($GLOBALS);` on top and see in plain text what it returns. Are the superglobals populated as on your local system?

Comment: @hakre problem appears with default theme and no plugins. it's a server issue.

Comment: Add your PHP + Wordpress version to your question please. Also if you have specifics about the server (at least the OS) would be nice for future users. Check the ini settings that are outlined in comments/answers, too. They should help in troubleshooting this.

Comment: @Adnan I've read the docs and `request_order` being blank means PHP should use the values in `variables_order`

Comment: @matt: Yes, according to the docs, `request_order` should then be `"GPCS"`. Also `wp_magic_quotes` should set the value of the superglobal.

Comment: @hakre so are you saying this is a Wordpress bug? BTW var_dump($GLOBALS) has content, but var_dump($_REQUEST) is empty

Comment: @matt: No, I'm not jumping to such a conclusions that fast. Probably related: [why is $_REQUEST empty](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5701588/367456)

Comment: Do you have any mod_rewrite rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: @matt, I have come across the same situation several times and, for reasons I can't explain, I always had to mess around with `request_order` and `variables_order`, sometimes one is blank and the other is `'GPC'`, sometimes it's the opposite, and each combination produced different cases in different environments. Maybe there's something wrong with my understanding of them. But anyway, if you haven't done so already try to fill both of them with `'GPCS'`.

Answer (score 2):

Check two directives

1) request_order
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order

2) variables_order
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Comment: have added this info to the post, as numerous people have asked me to check

Answer (score 0):

Verify your php.ini configuration. There is an option request_order that must be set to "On" and Value to be "GP" for Get and Post.

It's turned off.. But here's what mine looks like on my local ini from WAMP.

```
; request_order
;   Default Value: None
;   Development Value: "GP"
;   Production Value: "GP"
```

Comment: This does not mean it will leave the super globals array REQUEST empty.