# Common causes for $_REQUEST[var] to be null?

Tags: php, wordpress, request

What are some common causes that `$_REQUEST[var]` would be null?

I'm passing `&redirect_to=somevalue`   in the URI.  When I test `$_REQUEST['redirect_to']` in the receiving PHP code, it appears to be unset.  Could this be caused be a server environment configuration issue?  I'm on ZippyKid and I know they are pretty serious about security.

UPDATE: This is still not fixed.  Read comments below. Once everyone helped me realize the problem might be the URL I was passing as the value of 'redirect_to', I went to do that.  But then I discovered, I was temporarily using the word 'blah'.  So right now I'm hitting this:

http://mysite.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword&sidedoorkey=2738jksdf98143lkadsf9534sdfadsf3f2321asdf53&redirect_to=blah

But php says $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] is a zero length string.  O_o

Comment: What do you see when you do `var_dump($_REQUEST)`? If it's empty, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701588/why-is-request-empty)

Comment: Good call on the var_dump().   I should have just done that.  It dumps out an array that shows all the variables as expected, but it includes this: ["redirect_to"]=> string(0)   so obviously its picking up redirect_to from the url.. and the problem must be the particular string i'm passing it.  its a query string and some of the characters must throw a problem.

Comment: Michael, thank you for the suggestion.  I am well aware of this.  Wordpress's archaic login implementation uses REQUEST.  I'm stuck with it.

Comment: It's weird that the variable exists, but contains nothing.  That's not server configuration.  What does your real `somevalue` look like?  Is it properly URL encoded?

Comment: Well I didn't realize it had to be encoded until I did the var_dump as suggested.  When I googled, people were saying to use javascript encodeURI() but I read the docs and knew that wouldn't help.  However, I now see that there is another one for taking care of URLs that have queries in them: javascript  encodeURIComponent()

Comment: I'm silly.  I had already accounted for this.  See the Update above.  Its still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet solved the problem, but I DID figure out a common cause for the problem so I'm answering the question with it.

I have a suspicion the problem is due to a "sticky" variable in a cookie.  If a cookie is set with the same variable it could override the value of a duplicate variable passed in _GET or _POST.

This is, naturally, the primary security concern with using _REQUEST and why its bad practice to use it.  Bah, stupid Wordpress old code!  Hopefully I can figure out whether my problem is actually a cookie var or not and then get the issue fixed.  I have poured over the code several times and see no problems anywhere else.

Comment: I never solved the problem.  I ended up doing a work-around in the PHP code.  It produced unnecessarily complex code. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use urlencode before every string  like redirect_to=urlencode('blah'):