# Failing to retrieve values in $_REQUEST in PHP using Twilio

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

Hi I am following this procedure and this php script work just fine on my web server:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/twiml/greet-caller-by-name

However, when I am trying to assign them to variables:

```
$contact = $_REQUEST['From']; 
$msg = $_REQUEST['Body'];
```

It did not find anything.

`var_dump($_REQUEST)` showed me `array(0)`. 
`var_dump($_GET)` and `var_dump($_POST)` also showed me `array(0)`.

But my text clearly went to the server as using the site's example worked just fine. Any clue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is $\_REQUEST empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701588/why-is-request-empty)

Comment: This script worked just fine though: if(!$name = $people[$_REQUEST['From']])
        $name = "Monkey";

Comment: And request_order was set to "GP": request_order = "GP"

Comment: var_dump($_GET) or var_dump($_POST) were both empty as well.