# $_REQUEST['url] is empty. How to get controller and methods from $_REQUEST['url']? Bitnami WAMP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, request

( This question was modified two times, because of answers and other information i found. )

I need to get url from REQUEST. Below is the example of index.php where i try to print request,post and get - all of them are empty. 
I have tried this on my computer with Bitnami WAMP and in remote server (Arvixe). Because it does not work on the remote server, maybe the reason is in .htaccess? Where else could be the reason that REQUEST['url'] is not working?

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\Plan2own\public\index.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//phpinfo();
echo'<br> index.php   _GET  = **', var_dump( $_GET  ), '**';  
echo'<br> index.php   _POST  = **', var_dump( $_POST  ), '**';  
echo'<br> index.php GLOBALS[_REQUEST]  = **', var_dump($GLOBALS['_REQUEST']) , '**'; 
echo'<br> index.php   _REQUEST  = **', var_dump( $_REQUEST  ), '**';  
echo'<br> index.php   _REQUEST[url]  = **', var_dump( $_REQUEST['url']  ), '**';
echo'<br> index.php   _GET[url]  = **', var_dump( $_GET['url']  ), '**';  
echo'<br> index.php   _POST[url]  = **', var_dump( $_POST['url']  ), '**';
```

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\Plan2own\public.htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0/apache2/htdocs/www/Plan2own/public
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

For example, using url `http://plan2own/index.php/home`  i am getting the following results and empty url.

```
index.php _GET = **array(0) { } **
index.php _POST = **array(0) { } **
index.php GLOBALS[_REQUEST] = **array(0) { } **
index.php _REQUEST = **array(0) { } **
index.php _REQUEST[url] = **NULL **
index.php _GET[url] = **NULL **
index.php _POST[url] = **NULL **
```

For example, using url `http://plan2own/index.php?a=b` i am getting empty url

```
index.php _GET = **array(1) { ["a"]=> string(1) "b" } **
index.php _POST = **array(0) { } **
index.php GLOBALS[_REQUEST] = **array(1) { ["a"]=> string(1) "b" } **
index.php _REQUEST = **array(1) { ["a"]=> string(1) "b" } **
index.php _REQUEST[url] = **NULL **
index.php _GET[url] = **NULL **
index.php _POST[url] = **NULL **
```

The idea is that i should get home from `http://plan2own/index.php/home`, i.e. i should get controller and methods.

I read `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701588/why-is-request-empty` (a) commenting out auto_globals_jit in php.ini and restarting apache did not help; (b) request_oder and variable_order in php.ini are correct in my case.

I am checking the correct php.ini file, which i can see using phpinfor(); in "Loaded Configuration File" line.

Answer (score 1):

Your question mentions `auto_globals_jit` and `require_order`.  Make sure `variables_order` in `php.ini` is set to something like:

```
variables_order = "GPCS";
```

There should be nothing besides this text on that line. ONce you've made a change to `php.ini` remember to restart PHP/the webserver.

Double-check that you're editing the correct `php.ini` file; there are often several of them. If you execute `phpinfo();exit;` and in the output look at the path in `Loaded configuration file`, it should match the path of your `php.ini`

Comment: The `request_order` and `variables_order` are enabled and correct. I am checking the correct `\C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\php\php.ini`, which is loaded if i uncomment `phpinfo();` in `index.php` . Do not understand where could be the error. Can it be in `.htaccess` ?

Comment: i have updates the question after trying the BeetleJuice answer

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, managed to get url in order to extract controller and method parameters using example from

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

1) In C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\Plan2own\public.htaccess
change `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]` to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

2) which redirects url to `index.php` and when one can analyze it using the code below.

// C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\www\Plan2own\public\index.php 
$request  = str_replace("/Plan2own/public/index.php/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 echo'
 index.php   request  = **', var_dump( $request  ), '**';

For url `http://www.domain.com/public/index.php/home/some` The result is `index.php request = **string(9) "home/some" **`

p.s. I could not get `$_REQUEST['url']`, because for some reason `.htaccess` command `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`, which was working on Linux, is not working in Arvixe and Bitnami WAMP.