# $_REQUEST not working after I moved from server to another

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, server

I moved my site from VPS server to another server on amazon. Both operating systems are Ubuntu.

I got everything working except that I can't get the $_REQUEST data working. I mean I did not change any code I just moved to the new server and this part of code after debugging $_REQUEST always return null.

Do I miss some PHP extensions or so? or something to be enabled? .htaccess

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Can you share example code? Have you compared both server's configuration?

Comment: $_REQUEST always return null.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any configuration that could cause that. this is what I'm asking about.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701588/why-is-request-empty - this question is a duplicated

Comment: one aside advice: avoid using `$_REQUEST` at all.